# Gobble up the [raspberry-pi] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Why do we have a [raspberry-pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi) on Stack Overflow?

The tag wiki describes what a [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) is and then has this at the bottom:

> Raspberry Pi.SE
>
> There is a Stack Exchange site dedicated to the Raspberry Pi, which is
>   currently in beta. If your question is specific to the Raspberry Pi,
>   it should be asked there. However, general programming questions,
>   which you happen to encounter on the Raspberry Pi are appropriate on
>   Stack Overflow.

So a couple of observations:

- The Stack Exchange network already has a complete site dedicated to Raspberry Pi questions that aren't programming based - setting up, configuring, whatever
- "Raspberry Pi" isn't a programming language or an OS.
- If you are asking a *programming* question for the Raspberry Pi then it will be in a language we already have a tag for, on an OS we already have a tag for.

I don't know how to find tag statistics, but there is around a 50% unanswered rate, and I struggle to find any real value added from the tag.

Burninate?

Comment: Hm. I can only reason that it is a semi-useful additional tag that indicates that resource restrictions will be in effect, which automatically invalidates the most likely popular answers of this modern day and age and can be the difference between a question being a duplicate or not. But I guess the question body should be the primary indicator of such restrictions, not a tag.

Comment: That tag is *highly* relevant to programming questions, the device does put up significant obstacles.  That there is another site where non-programming questions are on topic is entirely normal, it is the usual reason to create such a site.

Comment: @HansPassant can you point to some good questions that are tagged raspberry-pi (and for which having that tag adds value)  i scanned the last four or five pages of raspberry-pi questions and found none -- not one good raspberry specific question!

Answer (score 15):

As someone who has developed for the Raspberry Pi, I think this is a perfectly viable tag for Stack Overflow.

The Raspberry Pi has distinctive hardware that provides some interesting challenges on the programming side. For example, its GPU requires the use of proprietary Broadcom APIs that you're not going to use elsewhere. There are plenty of good programming questions to be asked about how to use APIs and hardware specific to this device.

As Hans states, just because another site exists on a broader subject on the network does not make programming questions about that subject off-topic on Stack Overflow. In my experience, the questions over at RPi.SE tend to focus on usage of the Raspberry Pi from a hardware or software angle, with programming-related questions still largely being asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There may be "plenty of good programming questions to be asked" but so far no one is asking them -- or at least the good questions are few and far between.   Almost all of the questions tagged Raspberry-pi are debian questions or general purpose linux questions that belong on Server Fault.  I'm not seeing many Raspbians talking directly to the hardware or the very low level APIs.).

Comment: *[C++ cout output on RPi 3B](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59231)* might be an example of the reverse case.

Answer (score 9):

I'm getting to this party late and it looks like the issue is already decided, but I want a recount.  I got here because I wanted to ask the same question as GPPK.  Can we, please, git rid of the [raspberry-pi] tag.

Why it matters to me: I currently have five Raspberry Pi's. Two are running "production" apps that I developed.  The other three are for just messin'-around.  I thought it would be a good idea to subscribe to the Raspberry Pi and Raspbian tags so I could see what issues people are encountering and possibly contribute answers.

What I've seen, however, is a lot of codswallop.  Bad questions. A lot of questions that are not at all related to the Raspberry-specific features, but are general Linux, Python, etc. questions.  And a lot of "how do I configure my system" questions that belong on Server Fault.

By the way the [raspbian] tag is even worse, and don't even get me started on [raspberry-pi2] and [raspberry-pi3].

The simple solution for me is to unsubscribe from the tags, but in the interest of improving the Stack Overflow community [Dale pats himself on the back] I wanted to suggest that the tag is counterproductive.

Tag Pros:

- The Raspberry Pi is a unique environment that presents unique programming challenges due to the unique hardware present on the device and some of the Raspberry Pi-only extensions to Debian.

Tag Cons:

- The Raspberry Pi is just another computer running [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) (or other OS's) so this tag is equivalent to having tags [Dell] [HP] [Asus] [Lenovo], ad nauseum.
- Raspberry Pi is not a unified environment.  There are several operating systems that run on the hardware and even more programming languages that you can use to develop software for the Raspberry Pi, thus there tends to be nothing in common between the questions that have this tag other than the (irrelevant) hardware being used by the questioner.
- With very few exceptions, the "good" questions that have this tag have nothing to do with its Raspberryness. They are questions that would occur on any Linux platform, or any Python programming environment, or any...

Counter proposal:

Most of the Raspberry Pi-specific hardware quirks are hidden from a typical developer by the OS. We don't have to know anything "special" to display video or to communicate with the USB ports, or to ....   The OS provides us a *cross platform* API that handles the details.

There are, however, two unique hardware features on a Raspberry Pi -- the GPIO ports, and the camera. Questions about developing software to interact with these are quite likely to be Raspberry Pi-specific and otherwise qualify as good Stack Overflow material.

Thus I propose creating tags [Raspberry-GPIO] and [Raspberry-Camera] for questions about developing software to interact with these specific hardware features of the Raspberry Pi and burninate all the other [Raspberry Pi...] tags.

Comment: Based on Brad's answer I'll add another tag to my suggestions [Raspberry-GPU].